# How to update sql query dynamically - jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to figure out how I can update my sql query dynamically.

On the main page, I have a pagination script that counts how many pages there will be:

```
<?php
function generate_pagination($sql) {
  include_once('config.php');
  $per_page = 3;

  //Calculating no of pages
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $pages = ceil($count/$per_page);

  //Pagination Numbers
  for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
  {
    echo '<li class="page_numbers" id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
  }
}
?>
```

I then have in the body of the same page this line of code to populate the page numbers:

```
<?php generate_pagination("SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category='marketing'"); ?>
```

So, that line is displaying the necessary amount of page numbers to be displayed for just the 'marketing' category.

The problem that I am having is with that single line of code. I want to make the category dynamic, so instead of it being hardcoded to 'marketing' I would like jquery to get the id of an element and place it in.

The element would be this link that I have on the same page:

```
<a href="#" class="category" id="marketing">Marketing</a>
```

So, when the user clicks that link, I am trying to place the id of the link in the category section of the query using jquery.

I hope that made sense, and if anyone can assist me on this that would be great.

Comment: Is this in an AJAX request, or a normal pageload?

Comment: This is an Ajax request.

Comment: Can you post your current ajax call?  Easier to directly answer that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the PHP side:

```
<?php
function generate_pagination($sql) {
  include_once('config.php');
  $per_page = 3;

  //Calculating no of pages
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $pages = ceil($count/$per_page);

  //Pagination Numbers
  for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
  {
    echo '<li class="page_numbers" id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
  }
}
?>

<?php generate_pagination("SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category='" . mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['category'] ) . "'"); ?>
```

Then in your jquery post:

```
$("a.category").click(function() {
  $.post("test.php", { category: $(this).attr("id") },
    function(data){
      //Load your results into the page
    });
});
```

On click we take the ID, pass it to the server as a post variable `category`, then on the server, grab it, escape it properly for security, and use that query.  Load your results the same way you are now, that part doesn't change.